# Meaning of "The evidence is in"

Tags: meaning

When you say "The evidence is in" or "The news are in", does it mean it has arrived? or does it mean it is here? Which one would be better for translation?

Comment: "It has arrived" means the same as "it is here" (roughly)  So I'm not very clear about your question.  Also "news" is treated as singular (don't ask why) so "The news is in"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The evidence is in" is an idiom, at least in the U.S., meaning that there is enough information available to make a decision or a conclusion. It is a polite way to say that there is no need for further discussion.

It literally means only that "evidence is available," but the definite article makes it clear that no material evidence is missing.